# What euphemisms were there in Old Spanish to speak about the sexual act?

Tags: etimología, solicitud-de-término, historia, eufemismos

I was looking for the etymology of the word *ensamblar* in Spanish. At first I looked at what the DLE says, but it only says that it comes from the Old French *ensembler*. So looking at other dictionaries, I finally found [this information](http://www.etymonline.com/word/assemble) about the English verb "assemble":

> [...] from Old French *assembler* "come together, join, unite; gather" (11c.), from Latin *assimulare* "to make like, liken, compare; copy, imitate; feign, pretend," later "to gather together," from assimilated form of *ad* "to" (see ad-) + *simulare* "to make like," from stem of *similis* "like, resembling, of the same kind" (see similar).

But what really amused me was the following bit of information:

> In Middle English and in Old French it also was a euphemism for "to couple sexually."

So now we know what was meant by "I'm going to assemble my husband tonight". But the euphemism is said to be used in Old French and Middle English. So was this also applied to [Old Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Spanish_language)? After all, the word *ensamblar* already appears in Spanish dictionaries from the 16th century, so it was probably used before that. If not, was there any known euphemism for the sexual act that was used in Old Spanish?

Comment: Tirar la barra es uno de mis favoritos jajaja

Comment: @guifa pues si se usaba en el medievo, anímate y escribe una respuesta con ese y otros que te sepas. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out of my head, I know that ***ayuntarse*** was one of them. In fact it still appears in the DLE with that meaning, although marked as "desus" (not used anymore):

> **[ayuntar](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=ayuntar)**.
> Der. del ant. ayunto 'junta', y este del lat. adiunctus 'junto'.
>
> 3. prnl. desus. Realizar el coito.

Some examples of its use c. 1400:

> E veyendose el muy fuerte enflamado e cabtivado para pecar, e los sus pensamientos para salut de la moça e para conversion a Dios, puestas asy commo manjar en anzuelo, era çerca del fazimiento, e los enemigos, faziendole entender que non era pecado por la salud del alma **ayuntarse** una vez a la moger, llorando la mengua de la su alma, somitiendo a sy mismo, luego se torno a la oraçion (...)
> <sub>Anónimo, *Barlaam e Josafat (manuscrito S)*, c. 1400.</sub>
>
> Item saluia motañesa, dada
> a comer a los puercos monteses, o a
> qualesquier otros animales, quando
> quieren **ayuntarse**, luego se empreñara:
> o los poluos de los genitales del
> puerco que nunca fue castrado: si jelos
> dieres a beuer en vino a la mujer, quando se enxuga del mestruo, le aprouechara
> para concebir.
> <sub>Anónimo, *Traducción del Compendio de la humana salud de Johannes de Ketham*, c. 1400-1500.</sub>

Comment: Muy buena, de hecho lo que se entendía por "assemble" y "ayuntarse" era más o menos lo mismo, así que podría decirse que el eufemismo de la pregunta también se usaba (con una ligera variación) en España.